# How to make a query based in a FK?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

I have two models. in my View, I want a return what reference Model1 to Model2, filtering the user logged attributed a ModelTwo. Here is my models.py

```
ModelOne(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True)
description = models.TextField()

ModelTwo(models.Model):
model_one = models.ForeignKey(ModelOne, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
```

In my view, I want a result get user has attributed ModelTwo getting PK to ModelOne.

I tryied this, but the PK is getting is the ModelTwo, and I want PK for ModelOne:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return ModelTwo.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
```

I saw `'__'`(underscore, underscore) to make querys about another classes(FK), but I did not make it. Another thing, is `related_name`, with have a form to make with this, its interesting to use.

Can anyone help me? Thanks a lot for your attention my friends.

Comment: Wait what are you trying to return? Are you trying to get the users attached or the model_ones attached?

Comment: I trying return objects the ModelTwo have the same object for ModelOne. Like for Object for name= "Duck" the ModelOne, I want all objects from ModelTwo what have the same object by ModelOne(name="Duck) for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, do remember that ForeignKey is a one to many relationship. There can be multiple ModelTwo records connected to the same user. To get all ModelTwo records for a user you can either do `ModelTwo.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)` or using the default related name `user.modeltwo_set.all()`.

To get all ModelOnes you can use something like

```
ModelOne.objects.filter(id__in=user.modeltwo_set.values_list('pk'
, flat=True))
```

And you can use related_name in your model definition to replace the default.

Comment: I'm using generic.CreateView, and a try this and didn't work, the name "user" is not defined.

Comment: user is supposed to contain the user you are trying to find objects for

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have a few options:

If you just need the `ModelOne` PKs then:

```
set(ModelTwo.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).values_list('model_one__pk', flat=True))
```

I used `set` to remove duplicates.

Another option - get the `ModelOne`s which have a relation to `ModelTwo` with the appropriate user. I think it's better:

```
ModelOne.objects.filter(model_two_set__user=self.request.user).values_list('pk', flat=True)
```